# combing two sets of integers using removeDifferent() and removeSame()

Tags: c++

Kind of stumped on what to do next here. I have to create a class called IntSet, which represents a mathematical set of integers using the following data members:

**A pointer-to-int that will point to a dynamically allocated array that holds the values currently in the IntSet**

**An int that holds the current size of the array (that needs to be updated whenever the add() method creates a larger array**
**

**An int that holds the number of values currently in the IntSet (it will need to be updated in the add() and remove() methods.**

Most of the program is complete except for this last part, which requires me to combine two sets of integers and have them interact with each other. I have to use the following:

removeDifferent(): setA.removeDifferent(setB) should remove from setA any values that are not also in setB.

removeSame(): setA.removeSame(setB) should remove from setA any values that are also in setB.

Header:

```
#include <iostream>

class IntSet{

public:

    void print(); //prints IntSet

    IntSet(); //Constructor
    ~IntSet(); //Destructor
    int size(); //returns number of values currently in IntSet
    bool isEmpty(); //returns true if IntSet contains no integers. False otherwise
    bool contains(int i) const; //returns true if a value is in IntSet. False otherwise.
    void add(int i); //adds a value to IntSet. If current array is full, allocate a new array that is twice as big.
    void remove(int i); //removes value from IntSet by shifting over all of the subsequent values in the array.
    void addAll()
    void removeDifferent()
    void removeSame()

//----helper methods----
int getIndex(int integer); //returns the integer on an index


private:
    int* ptr; //points to a dynamically allocated array that holds the values currently in IntSet
    int sizeOfArray; //holds current size of Array
    int numberOfValues; //holds number of values currently in IntSet

};
```

Main:

```
#include "IntSet.hpp"
#include <iostream>

//prints IntSet

void IntSet::print(){
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++){
        std::cout << ptr[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

//delcaring variables 

IntSet::IntSet(){

    numberOfValues = 0;
    sizeOfArray = 10;
    ptr = new int[10];

}

IntSet::~IntSet(){

    delete[] ptr;

}

//Returning the number of values in the IntSet

int IntSet::size(){

    return numberOfValues;

}

//Determining whether the stack is empty

bool IntSet::isEmpty(){

    if(numberOfValues == 0){
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}

//defining contains() function

bool IntSet::contains(int i) const
{

    for (int k = 0; k < numberOfValues; k++){
        if (ptr[k] == i){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

//defining add() function

void IntSet::add(int i){

    if (contains(i)){
        return;
    }
    if (numberOfValues == sizeOfArray)
    {
        sizeOfArray = sizeOfArray * 2; //doubling size of arrayCapacity

        int* temp = new int[sizeOfArray]; //allocating new one that's twice as large

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = ptr[i]; //copying old stuff into new one
        }

        delete[] ptr; //deallocate old array
        ptr = temp; //set ptr to new array
    }
    ptr[numberOfValues] = i;
    numberOfValues++;

}

void IntSet::remove(int i){
    if(!contains(i)){
        return;
    }
    bool bIntRemoved = false;
    for(int k=0; k < numberOfValues; k++){
        // check if we are currently searching or shifting
        if(!bIntRemoved){
            if(ptr[k] == i){
                // found the int to remove
                bIntRemoved = true;
            }
        }else if(k < numberOfValues-1){
            ptr[k] = ptr[k+1];
        } // else, we are at the last index and we have nothing to shift
    }
    numberOfValues--;
    }
    int IntSet::getIndex(int index){
        return ptr[index];
    }

    void IntSet::addAll(IntSet b){
        for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++){
            add(b.getIndex(i));
        }
    }
```

How can I incorporate my add() and remove() functions to combine two sets of integers and have them follow these rules? I don't even know how to begin to write them :(

Thank you all!

EDIT: addAll() is completed, but the other two are still not clicking

Comment: Err, C++ has a `std::set<T>`. Are you recreating this because you want to/need to, or can you use the standard library?

Comment: yeah, i have to do it this way unfortunately.

Comment: Well.. the exercise looks like you were supposed to reinvent std::vector to re-implement std::set in the least performant way. What of STL  **are** you allowed to use?

Comment: Understood. C++ implements `std::set` as a tree. I'd recommend trying to implement a binary tree which makes finding unique elements trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've already implemented your contains method and assuming you've done so correctly, you should use that method when implementing your other functions.

```
removeDifferent(IntSet setB){
  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++){
    if(!setB.contains(ptr[i])){
       remove(ptr[i]);
       i--; //make sure not to skip any elements by moving back one
    }
  } 
} //end of removeDifferent

removeSame(IntSet setB){
  for(int i = 0; i < numberOfValues; i++){
    if(setB.contains(ptr[i])){
       remove(ptr[i]);
       i--; //make sure not to skip any elements by moving back one
    }
  } 
} //end of removeSame
```

As for your add all function, I don't think there is a good way to add the elements of the other list because the int* ptr is private and there are no methods that return any elements. Theoretically, you could scan every single possible integer value, but this is definitely not ideal and likely not the intended solution. Are you sure all the methods here are correct?

```
#include <climits> //need to include that for this one

void addAll(IntSet setB){
  for(int i = INT_MIN; i < INT_MAX && !setB.isEmpty(); i++){
    int removals = 0; 
    while(setB.contains(i)){ //temporarily remove all i's in setB
       removals++;
       add(i);
       setB.remove(i);
    }
    while(removals > 0){ //add back all i's that we previously removed
       setB.add(i);
       removals--;
    }
  }
}
```

I haven't checked if these compiles, but this is definitely the basic idea for these functions.

Good luck